# datacontext not found in vs2010 sp1

Tags: asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

I am starting to learn some linq and there is a place where I need to use datacontent, but it seems that the IntelliSense can't found any datacontent.
Am I missing something?
I am running VS2010 SP1.
Screenshot attached.
Thanks in advance for your help.[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have tagged your question with `asp.net` and the screenshot you have attached illustrates a WinForms project. May I ask why?

Comment: that's my bad. I tried asp.net page too, I did got the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext` is defined in the `System.Data.Linq` namespace, which you don't have in your using statements. Make sure the `System.Data.Linq` assembly is referenced, then add that using statement.

Comment: I have referenced System.Linq if you can see. I tried referencing System.Data.Linq but there is no option for Linq under Data. I think that was an option in the older VS editions. Thanks for helping

Comment: Is your project set to use the Client subset of the .NET Framework?

Comment: Actually, I just checked and it works fine with the Client Profile. Are you sure you have the `System.Data.Linq` assembly referenced? You said "if you can see" in your previous comment, but in your screenshot it isn't possible to see your references.